# What Factors that affect ping to a dynamic IP?

Tags: networking, ping, traceroute

If i'm going to test the ping between me and my friend, will interleaved mode that applied by cabinet would affect his connection and expect an increase in the latency/ping to his machine regardless of distance?

Comment: Your question is too vague. Are you having a problem? What is DSL interleaved mode supposed to do for your? Was it not enabled first? Cabinet is street distribution point?

Comment: Well that's not the point, i was just assuming. i only want to know if whether dynamic IPs has an alternative effect when it comes to ping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether your IP is assigned via DHCP or static it should not effect how ping operates.  Once the IP is assigned ICMP does not care how you got it.